# How to transfer eth to a solidity function from a Dapp

Tags: solidity, dapp-development, dapps

I am trying to build a Dapp which includes functionality to deposit funds to a contract and withdraw them. 
The functions look like this

```
function fundContract() public payable {
        require (msg.sender == users[msg.sender].addr);
        users[msg.sender].balance += msg.value;
        contractBalance+=msg.value;

    }


function withdraw (uint amount) public onlyUser() payable{

        require (msg.sender == users[msg.sender].addr);
        require (amount > 0);
        require (amount <= users[msg.sender].balance);

        msg.sender.transfer(amount);

        users[msg.sender].balance -= amount;
        contractBalance-= amount;
    }
```

I understand that there will be a function call to withdraw() specifying the amount parameter from the front end using web3.js send() command, but how do I provide the msg.value for the fundContract method from the viewpoint of a Dapp. 
Remix allows specifying the value in the message , but I can't find a way to do so for a Dapp.

Comment: Whatever library you're using, there will be a way to attach ether to a transaction. Let us know what library, and we can point you to the relevant documentation. Web3.js is a likely candidate for what you're going to use, and there are two significant versions: 0.20.x and 1.0 beta.

Comment: @smarx I am building on Qtum and using QtumJS which is similar to web3.js 
The answer by Sam makes it clear how to use it with web3 and I found a similar way with QtumJS. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the value field, then call the contract send method.

https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-contract.html#methods-mymethod-send

```
myContract.methods.fundContract().send({value: 'AMOUNT IN WEI'})
```